# How do I find the difference between two values in one column by cross-referencing them against values in another column?

Tags: sql, mysql, string, equals

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | machine | date | status
----------------------------
1  | 1 | 01-01-2009 | New
1  | 1 | 01-01-2010 | Busted
1  | 2 | 01-01-2010 | New
1  | 1 | 01-01-2012 | Repaired
```

I need to know the differences in date between each status PER machine, if it is the most recent status and there is no newer status for that machine, it needs to show the difference between the last date listed and the current date:

```
id | machine | date | status   | duration
---------------------------------------
1  | 1 | 01-01-2009 | New      | 1 year
1  | 1 | 01-01-2010 | Busted   | 2 years
1  | 2 | 01-01-2010 | New      | 2 years, 2 months, 5 days
1  | 1 | 01-01-2012 | Repaired | 2 months, 5 days
```

To be quite honest, I don't care how the new duration column displays the distances between dates. I attempted to make this query myself but failed.

Comment: Do you have to do this in MySQL or could you do it with PHP,PERL,Ruby,etc?

Answer (score 7):

This will give you the values in days -

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(IFNULL((SELECT `date` FROM machine_status ms2 WHERE ms1.machine = ms2.machine AND ms1.`date` < ms2.`date` ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 1), CURRENT_DATE), ms1.`date`)
FROM machine_status ms1;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way is to get the last two records for each machine and then compare the dates (simple subtraction) in your code to find out the difference.

I found [this article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) that describes how to use GROUP BY with two objects (to get only the last two of each machine)

In order to sort by date, you might have to change the way you store dates. It is common to use a Unix Timestamp.